# She seems to be in a better mood than (what) she was in before. --meaning difference

Tags: sentence-meaning, relative-clauses

> She seems to be in a better mood **than** she was in before.
>
> She seems to be in a better mood **than what** she was in before.

Are both the above sentences grammatically correct? They have a different grammatical form, which is confusing. What, if anything, is the difference in their meaning?

Comment: Hi, lekon. Isn't there supposed to be "was" after "what" in the second example?

Comment: @Rathony. Yes. 
I missed out on that word while i was typing the entire thing.

Comment: +1 Superb question. One of the best I've seen in months. Don't understand why it's closed :(

Comment: @Araucaria, I post questions here almost regularly. 
And i'd love it if someone were to help me rid me of the various kinds of doubts i have over text.
Would you like to discuss this in a chat room over text?

Comment: @Araucaria, feel free to say no though.

Comment: @lekonchekon Sure. Can't do it today though. Am mad busy!

Comment: @Araucaria, i could make a chat room for us, that way, i'd get to ask you questions there, and you could respond to them questions when you have time on your hands.

Comment: To be in a better mood than the one she was in before. The second sentence is not grammatical. There is no reason to put what in the sentence.

Comment: It is a far, far better thing that I do, than what I have ever done; it is a far, far better rest that I go to, than what I have ever known.

Answer (score 2):

> She seems to be in a better mood than she was in before. `CORRECT`
>
> She seems to be in a better mood than what she was in before. `INCORRECT`

**Than** is a conjunction that connects two clauses or coordinates words in the same clause.

In this case, `she was in before` is the **subordinate clause**, and more specifically a type of subordinate clause known as a **comparative clause**, which usually follows the **comparative form of an adjective or adverb** (in this case `better` is the comparative form of the adjective *good*), and begins with *than*, *like*, or *as* (in this case `than`).

---

## Why is the first example correct?

> She seems to be in a better mood than she was in before. `CORRECT`

In this example, the main clause `She seems to be in a better mood` is **defining** the **subject** as `She`, the **object** as `better mood`, and the **verb** as `seems` (where `seems to be` follows a 'Seem + *to*-infinitive format and `be` is the linking verb).

Because those have been defined in the **main clause**, we do not need to (but can if we want) repeat the process of defining them in the **subordinate (comparative) clause**, unless we want to change or add meaning.

To illustrate this I'll use two grammatically correct examples, which have slightly different meanings.

> She seems to be in a better mood **than before**. `CORRECT`
>   <sub>**Meaning:** The subject, `She`, **seems to be** in a better mood than she **seemed to be** before</sub>.
>
> She seems to be in a better mood **than she was in before**. `CORRECT`
>   <sub>**Meaning:** The subject, `She`, **seems to be** in a better mood than she **was** before</sub>.

Notice that by adding `she was in`, you are changing the **meaning** because now you're saying that she *definitely was* in a better mood than she *seems to be now*, whereas without the `she was`, you're saying that she *seemed to be* in a better mood before than she *seems to be* now.

So, because you defined everything in your main clause, there was no need to do it again in your subordinate clause, but you did, by adding `she was`, you changed the verb from *seem* to *is*, which changed the meaning. Both are grammatically correct, but mean different things.

---

## Why is the second example incorrect?

> She seems to be in a better mood than what she was in before. `INCORRECT`

In your **main clause**, `She seems to be in a better mood`, you are saying that the **subject**, `She`, seems to be in the **object**, which you have defined as `mood`.

So the reader already knows what she was in, we do not need to define it a second time in the **subordinate clause** unless we **want to change the meaning**.

When you say `than what she was in`, you are saying that she was in something else, something *other* than a `mood`, or a `good mood`, but the reader cannot discern from this sentence what it was that she was in. Was she in a house? In a trance? In a movie? All we know is that she was `in` a common noun.

By using *what* in the subordinate clause like that you are explicitly implying `she` was in something, a thing (common noun), *something other than a mood*, without actually defining what that thing is, rendering it nonsensical.

This sort of structure is not *always* incorrect, though, and is used often as a metaphor.

Example:

> His car is a hell of a lot better **than what** he was driving before. `CORRECT`
>   <sub>**Meaning:** The subject, `car`, **is** much better than **the thing** he was driving before.</sub>

Notice how in this example, the writer is using the `than what` structure to refer to an undefined common noun, **a thing**, that `he` was driving before. We can assume from the verb `driving` that whatever the **thing** was, at least we know it was drivable, but technically speaking, from a grammatical stance, it could be referring to absolutely anything, any common noun, any **thing** that can be driven (and note that it could be driven according to all definitions of *drive*, and it could be driven metaphorically). We can't know because the writer is awkwardly leaving it undefined.

In this example, though, we can infer that it is a metaphor used to refer to the **subject's** previous vehicle as a 'thing', to denote condescension, to denote a sense of inferiority when compared to the `better` car that he is driving now.

In short: sometimes it can be used correctly, but one has to understand exactly what meaning they are trying to convey before consulting grammar and structuring a sentence correctly.